# Android Google Play Location

Tags: gps, location

How to get location from only GPS not with Network provider.

I know this can manage with the old verion of Location classes but How can i manage with updated library.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) out.

You can use only the GPS part but be warned that GPS consumes a lot of batery...

Use it wisely!